# whether tripitak talk about marananusati or maranassati?

Tags: mindfulness

I find many monks  discussing about marananusati... however I never find this word in tripitak.  Instead I find maranassati.

Do buddha ever talked about marananusati.

Comment: So, you are asking about "recollection or remembrance of death" vs. "mindfulness of death"?

Comment: yes. but I am not asking meaning . I am asking about reference for marananusati.? where it has stated in tripitaka?

Comment: Your question context are slightly crude.

Comment: In the Tipitaka/Sutta "Sati" is defined as "Saritaa or Anussaritaa" which is "Sati or Anussati". Atthakata/Visuddhimagga says Anussati is "Repeated Sati". No text says Sati is present moment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Marananussathi is discussed in Tipitaka. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but Maranassathi and Marananussathi are same isn't it?

Please refer

1. KN 1 (Mahāniddesa - Aṭṭhakavagga  -> [1. Kāmasuttaniddesa](https://suttacentral.net/mnd1/pli/ms?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)).

> Buddhānussatiṁ bhāventopi vikkhambhanato kāme parivajjeti,
> dhammānussatiṁ bhāventopi …pe… saṅghānussatiṁ bhāventopi …
> sīlānussatiṁ bhāventopi … cāgānussatiṁ bhāventopi … devatānussatiṁ
> bhāventopi … ānāpānassatiṁ bhāventopi … Variant: ānāpānassatiṁ →
> ānāpānasatiṁ (bj); ānāpāṇassatiṁ (pts-vp-pli1)**maraṇassatiṁ** bhāventopi
> … kāyagatāsatiṁ bhāventopi … upasamānussatiṁ bhāventopi vikkhambhanato
> kāme parivajjeti.

> Buddhānussatiṁ bhāventopi vikkhambhanato kāme parivajjeti,
> dhammānussatiṁ bhāventopi …pe… saṅghānussatiṁ bhāventopi …
> sīlānussatiṁ bhāventopi … cāgānussatiṁ bhāventopi … devatānussatiṁ
> bhāventopi … ānāpānassatiṁ bhāventopi … Variant: ānāpānassatiṁ →
> ānāpānasatiṁ (bj); ānāpāṇassatiṁ (pts-vp-pli1)**maraṇassatiṁ** bhāventopi
> … kāyagatāsatiṁ bhāventopi … upasamānussatiṁ bhāventopi vikkhambhanato
> kāme parivajjeti.

Also see,

2. [AN8.73 Paṭhamamaraṇassatisutta](https://suttacentral.net/an8.73/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)
3. [AN6.20 Dutiyamaraṇassatisutta](https://suttacentral.net/an6.20/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Comment: There is difference betwewen anusati and sati. anusati is remembering. whereas sati is in present moment.

Comment: @enRaiser Can you find that difference in Tipitaka? Where you found Sati is present moment?

Comment: for that there will not be single line.. what you need to do is, search all the occurrence of SAti and anusati and make sense from the context they are used. for example satima means be mindful. but you will not find any word like anusatima.  THeer is another word patisati whi means mare mindfulness.

Answer (score 0):

I don't care whatever people think "is this wholesome is in Tipitaka or not?" because  it's always truth whether "maraṇassatiṃ bhāveti" is an important meditation no matter whatever people said.

[ekakanipāta,pāḷi 43 paṇṇe](https://5000y.men/?rm.r.17.43...mara%E1%B9%87a#hl)

> *maraṇasaññaṃ bhāveti…* āhāre paṭikūlasaññaṃ bhāveti… sabbaloke anabhiratisaññaṃ [anabhiratasaññaṃ (sī. syā. kaṃ. pī.)] bhāveti…
> aniccasaññaṃ bhāveti… anicce dukkhasaññaṃ bhāveti… dukkhe anattasaññaṃ
> bhāveti… pahānasaññaṃ bhāveti… virāgasaññaṃ bhāveti… nirodhasaññaṃ
> bhāveti….
>
> [463-472] aniccasaññaṃ bhāveti… anattasaññaṃ bhāveti… *maraṇasaññaṃ
> bhāveti…* āhāre paṭikūlasaññaṃ bhāveti… sabbaloke anabhiratisaññaṃ
> bhāveti… aṭṭhikasaññaṃ bhāveti… puḷavakasaññaṃ [puḷuvakasaññaṃ (ka.)]
> bhāveti… vinīlakasaññaṃ bhāveti… vicchiddakasaññaṃ bhāveti…
> uddhumātakasaññaṃ bhāveti….
>
> [473-482] buddhānussatiṃ bhāveti… dhammānussatiṃ bhāveti…
> saṅghānussatiṃ bhāveti… sīlānussatiṃ bhāveti… cāgānussatiṃ bhāveti…
> devatānussatiṃ bhāveti… ānāpānassatiṃ bhāveti… **maraṇassatiṃ
> bhāveti**… kāyagatāsatiṃ bhāveti… upasamānussatiṃ bhāveti….

[Upajjhatthana Sutta](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.057.than.html): Subjects for Contemplation

(Actually it's not often do, it is always doing continuously.)

> "There are these five facts that one should reflect on often, whether
> one is a woman or a man, lay or ordained. Which five?
>
> "'I am subject to aging, have not gone beyond aging.' This is the
> first fact that one should reflect on often, whether one is a woman or
> a man, lay or ordained.
>
> "'I am subject to illness, have not gone beyond illness.' ...
>
> "'I am subject to death, have not gone beyond death.' ...
>
> "'I will grow different, separate from all that is dear and appealing
> to me.' ...
>
> "'I am the owner of my actions,[2](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.057.than.html) heir to my actions, born of my
> actions, related through my actions, and have my actions as my
> arbitrator. Whatever I do, for good or for evil, to that will I fall
> heir.' ...
>
> "These are the five facts that one should reflect on often, whether
> one is a woman or a man, lay or ordained.
>
> ...

And much more Suttas.

Answer (score 0):

Meditation basically into to stages

01.Samatha
02.Vidarshana[Vipassana]

To Investigate about this real world we need to acquire a Samadhi. For this purposes lord buddha taught us those meditation methods.
Lord buddha showed us 40 ways to conduct meditation and those 40 ways called "Sama Sathalis Karmasthana". Those who wanted to start meditaion, first need to identify him or herself. Their characters. Then accordingly they need to choose their Karmasthana.

Karmasthana basically works against their characteristics and bring them neutral or clam.  Example: If you are an angered person you need to practise Metta Bhavana. if you are a lusty person you need to practise asubha bhavana.  If you cannot figure out where you place yourself exactly start with Anapanasathi.

That is why **we are advised to take Monks or Guru's guidance and advices before starting the meditation.**  To select suitable "Kamatana". Not only that while meditating you may be arising questions or points that need to sortout then and there and clear the mind about those questions. I am talking about the meditation that leads to Nibbana.

Those 40 methods are:
These 40 classic and orthodox meditation subjects are:

I. The 10 Kasina  exercises: Kasina = 'Entirety'. All 4 jhānas possible.
1: Earth kasina,
2: Water kasina,
3: Fire kasina,
4: Wind kasina,
5: Blue kasina,
6: Yellow kasina,
7: Red kasina,
8: White kasina,
9: Light or consciousness kasina,
10: Space kasina.

II. The 10 perceptions of disgust: asubha-sañña: 1st jhāna possible:

1. A swollen and bloated corpse,
2. a bluish livid corpse,
3. a rotting corpse,
4. a cut-up and split corpse,
5. a gnawed corpse,
6. a hacked corpse,
7. a spread scattered corpse,
8. a bloody corpse,
9. a corpse of maggots,
10. a skeleton.

III. The 10 contemplations: remembrances or recollections anussati:

1. On the Buddha,
2. The Dhamma,
3. The Noble Sangha community,
4. Morality,
5. Generosity,
6. Heavenly divine beings,
7. **Death-Marananussathi**,
   7.1.  [To Learn More Click this Link](https://tricycle.org/magazine/death-awareness/),
   7.2.  [More about Marana sathi](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mara%E1%B9%87asati),
   7.3.  [How to Start Meditating on Death (A Guide for Beginners)](https://www.joincake.com/blog/death-meditation/),
8. Body,
9. In-and-out-breathing: All 4 jhānas  possible!,
10. Peace.

IV. The 4 divine abodes or infinite states: brahma-vihāra:

1. All-embracing friendliness = mettā,
2. Pity = karunā,
3. Mutual joy = muditā,
4. Equanimity = upekkhā,
   All 4 jhānas successively possible.

V. The 4 formless spheres arūpāyatana: based on the 4th jhāna:

1. The infinitude of space,
2. The infinitude of consciousness,
3. Empty nothingness,
4. Neither-perception-nor-non-perception.

VI. Perception of the loathsomeness of food āhāre patikkūla-saññā:

VII. Defining Analysis of the four great elements dhātu-vavatthāna:.

Now you know Where exactly Marananussathi Bhawana includes in Buddhism.  Also, above articles I saw many sutta's mentioned about Marananussathi. Follow the links that you have provided so that you can learn more about meditaion.

May Triple Gem Bless You!!!

Comment: The question is very simple and sort. Is it maranassati or marnanusati. Or both.and uf both what's difference?

Comment: There is no difference both are same.  Just the two words using same thing.  marana sathi in Sinhala marananussathi in Pali that also using in Sinhala.  The issue sometimes Google Translation getting differently  because of the typing language.